# How does High Replication Datastore implement consistent reads

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, distributed-system, consistency

I watched the video in the link below to understand how the High Replication Datastore works. Writes are synchronously replicated to a majority of the replicas and the remaining replicas receive the update asynchronously. The video says that reads are consistent. That even if a read hits a datacenter with stale data the datacenter will catch up with new updates. But how does it know whether or not it has stale data. Presumably it doesn't query every replica on each read?

http://www.google.com/events/io/2011/sessions/more-9s-please-under-the-covers-of-the-high-replication-datastore.html

Comment: I believe it's done with a log - initially a log is created before any writes happen so presumably that log is checked also before reads. How that replicates out across N datastores with a single log I can't imagine!

Comment: The HRD docs link to this paper: http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/research.google.com/en/us/archive/paxos_made_live.pdf

Comment: You can also look at this paper http://www.cidrdb.org/cidr2011/Papers/CIDR11_Paper32.pdf

Comment: Note that only ancestor queries have strong consistency.  According to this page (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries#Ancestor_Filters), most of the queries are eventually consistent (which means that the read may be slightly stale for exactly the reason you describe).  Note that ancestor queries are limited to a single entity group that is limited to 1 write/second.  This doesn't  directly answer your question though.